# Get Color at position Webgl

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, canvas, webgl

I want to debug my html5 canvas in Chrome console. I want to get the pixel color at position (445, 650).

I tried with this code:

```
var example = document.getElementById('glcanvas');
var context = example.getContext('webgl');
var pixels = new Uint8Array(context.drawingBufferWidth * context.drawingBufferHeight * 4); 
var data = context.readPixels(445, 650, context.drawingBufferWidth, context.drawingBufferHeight, context.RGBA, context.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

When I run those lines one by one, I get:

```
example
<canvas class="topleft" id="glcanvas" width="479" height="716" tabindex="1" contenteditable="true" style="cursor: default; width: 479px; height: 616px;"></canvas>

context
WebGLRenderingContext {vertexAttribDivisor: function, drawArraysInstanced: function, drawElementsInstanced: function, createVertexArray: function, deleteVertexArray: function…}

data
undefined
```

How can I get a **non-undefined** data? I am just trying to get the pixel color in HEX at the position (445, 650)

**SECOND ATTEMPT:**

```
var pixels = new Uint8Array(
    4 * context.drawingBufferWidth * context.drawingBufferHeight
);
var x = 445; 
var y = 650;
context.readPixels(
    0,
    0,
    context.drawingBufferWidth,
    context.drawingBufferHeight,
    context.RGBA,
    context.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    pixels
);
var pixelR = pixels[4 * (y * context.drawingBufferWidth + x)];
var pixelG = pixels[4 * (y * context.drawingBufferWidth + x) + 1];
var pixelB = pixels[4 * (y * context.drawingBufferWidth + x) + 2];
var pixelA = pixels[4 * (y * context.drawingBufferWidth + x) + 3];
```

All the pixels return 0 including:

```
pixels
Uint8Array(2268552) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0…]
```

Answer (score 3):

The `readPixels` function indeed doesn't return anything useful. The pixel data you're interested in is copied to `pixels` array:

```
var pixels = new Uint8Array(
    4 * context.drawingBufferWidth * context.drawingBufferHeight
);
context.readPixels(
    0,
    0,
    context.drawingBufferWidth,
    context.drawingBufferHeight,
    context.RGBA,
    context.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    pixels
);
// And here's components of a pixel on (x, y):
var pixelR = pixels[4 * (y * context.drawingBufferWidth + x)];
var pixelG = pixels[4 * (y * context.drawingBufferWidth + x) + 1];
var pixelB = pixels[4 * (y * context.drawingBufferWidth + x) + 2];
var pixelA = pixels[4 * (y * context.drawingBufferWidth + x) + 3];
```

Here `x` and `y` are coordinates of a pixel your want to inspect.

Comment: All of those 4 new pixels return 0 :(

Comment: @TSR If you haven't drawn anything to it, then those values are correct, all components of all pixels in the canvas are initialised to 0.

Comment: @KirillDmitrenko A bit late, but is it not true that this solution is very slow? I need to check at most two pixels for every single mouse event, so I assume that this would be terribly non-perflrmant (or maybe it would not that bad?) What would be an alternative that doesn't force synchronization?

Comment: @synchronizer Yep, due to synchronous nature of readPixel and sheer amount of work a browser need to do to actually get that pixel, it may become a bottleneck. What I've done in my app is I read an area of framebuffer instead of single pixel and cache read data. Since mouse movements are pretty contiguous, there's good chance next "lookup" will go into that cached area.

Comment: @KirillDmitrenko Hmmm... I see. In my case I just realized that I will only check pixels when the image isn't changing. Does this mean that I could cache something from the framebuffer when nothing new is being drawn and check those pixels? Would keeping a 640 x 480 cache at all times be "okay" (not TOO much memory).

Answer (score -1):

It says, that your canvas has just a height of 616, so the pixel is outside of the canvas.

Comment: That's not the problem. Reading pixels outside a framebuffer is a defined behaviour in WebGL, all the pixels will just be set to (0, 0, 0, 0).