# How to get the pixel color values from a WebGL Canvas in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas, webgl

I am working on a Chrome Extension that reads the image of a WebGL canvas on a specific site and checks the pixel color value of a couple certain locations. The issue I ran into however was the readPixels() function returning all 0's. I've tried adding the `{preserveDrawingBuffer: true}` tag, and creating a framebuffer (I think?) and neither of my implementations for either solution have worked. Here is my code. I know there is a way to take a screenshot of the entire webstite viewport, but for sake of simplicity and compatibility, it would be far easier to just find the specific canvas.

```js
async function getData(){ // this function is run on even keyup or keydown and executes properly
    console.log("getData function")
    const queue = document.getElementById("queueCanvas");
    console.log(queue);
    // pixel locations |v|
    // 35,60 // 35,160 // 35,200 // 35,275 // 35,350
    var gl = queue.getContext("webgl", {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
    // debug
    gl.viewport(0, 0, queue.width, queue.height);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0.5, 1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // debug (turn tha canvas background blue so that even if I search the wrong location, it should still give me a blue pixel
    var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    var tex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight, 0 , gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
    

    console.log(gl)

    var pixels = new Uint8Array(
        4 * gl.drawingBufferWidth * gl.drawingBufferHeight
    );
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.readPixels(
        0,
        0,
        gl.drawingBufferWidth,
        gl.drawingBufferHeight,
        gl.RGB,
        gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        pixels
    );
    console.log(pixels); // 0 0 0 0 0 ...
    var x = 35;
    var y = 60;
    var pixelR = pixels[4 * (y * gl.drawingBufferWidth + x)];
    var pixelG = pixels[4 * (y * gl.drawingBufferWidth + x) + 1];
    var pixelB = pixels[4 * (y * gl.drawingBufferWidth + x) + 2];

    console.log("pixel color " + pixelR+", "+pixelG+", "+pixelB); // 0,0,0

}
```

I have looked at stack overflow and found a couple results that did not work for me, and found a Google WebGL Dev Team forum post that also did not work. I concede however that these solutions may have been correct, but my implementations of said solutions are incorrect. Here are the three resources. [Get Color at position Webgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070167/get-color-at-position-webgl) [readPixels returns all zero](https://groups.google.com/g/webgl-dev-list/c/QaCSENwlNhY) [webgl readpixels is always returning 0,0,0,0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156971/webgl-readpixels-is-always-returning-0-0-0-0). It is important to note that the canvas is not mine, and I am not sure if its possible to access the canvas rendering code.

Additional semi-relevant info: The website in question is [Jstris](https://jstris.jezevec10.com/?play=2), and I am trying to access the queue of upcoming peices to analyze the best possible opener given the opening bag.

I will gladly follow up with any more information on the problem that you would need. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It looks like you are not drawing anything on the canvas so there is nothing to read? "reads the image of a WebGL canvas on a specific site", are you saying there is a `<canvas id="queueCanvas"></canvas>` element on some website and you are trying to read its pixels?

Comment: @teddybeard Yes, that is correct. I can also prove that there are pixels to read because I set the background on the canvas to blue successfully before trying to read the pixels. As I play the game, the upcoming pieces are drawn OVER the blue background, so everything seems to be functioning as normal.

Comment: How did you set the canvas color to blue? Did you use CSS `canvas.style.backgroundColor` or did you use `gl.clearColor(0, 0, 1, 1); gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`? It's possible you can change the CSS properties of the canvas but not access the gl context?

Comment: @teddybeard I used `gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0.5, 1); gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`, which is why I am so confused as well.

Comment: So you visibly got a blue canvas but not from readPixels because in your code comments it says `console.log(pixels); // 0 0 0 0 0 ...`. Is that right?

Comment: Correct, I get an array of 138240 0's, corresponding to the width*height*4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate your example and the one thing that appears incorrect is the pixel format `gl.RGB` in `gl.readPixels`. When I use `gl.RGB` in my example I get [0, 0, 0, 0] values, but when I use `gl.RGBA` I get the correct value. Could this be the issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
</body>
<script>
    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    const gl1 = canvas.getContext('webgl');
    const gl2 = canvas.getContext('webgl');

    gl1.clearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    gl1.clear(gl1.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    const out1 = new Uint8Array(4);
    const out2 = new Uint8Array(4);
    gl1.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl1.RGB, gl1.UNSIGNED_BYTE, out1);
    gl2.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl2.RGBA, gl2.UNSIGNED_BYTE, out2);
    console.log(out1);  // [  0, 0, 0,   0]
    console.log(out2);  // [255, 0, 0, 255]
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: That fixed it! MDN web docs told me I could use gl.RGB to weed out data I didn't need, but that did seem to be the issue, thank you!